# Node.js code loading inconsistently to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code tries to load from a csv file to a mongodb instance running on localhost.

**Problem** - It loads a different number of documents on every run (always less than total number of records in csv).

```
var csv = require('csv');

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, poolSize: 1});
var db = new Db('test', server);

db.open(function(err, db, onemore) {
  if(!err) {
    //Database connection is established.
    db.collection('teststocks', function(err, collection) {
      if(!err) {
        // Stocks collection is connected, open the file and insert the doc
        console.log("Trying to load from " + process.argv[2]);
        csv()
          .fromPath(process.argv[2], {
            columns: true
          })
          .on('data', function(data, index) {
            //data.stock = process.argv[2].substring(process.argv[2].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, process.argv[2].lastIndexOf('.'));
            collection.insert(data, {safe: true}, function(error, collection){
                    if ( error ) { console.log("Error inserting record : " + error); }
            });
            console.log("Inserted data for " + index);
          })
          .on('error', function(error) {
            db.close();
            console.log("Error: " + error);
          })
          .on('end', function(count) {
            console.log("Finished all writing.");
            db.close();
          });
      }
  });
  }
});
```

*P.S:  I am able to load the data using the mongoimport utility, but being a newcomer to node.js and mongodb; I'd like to understand the mistake I am making in the code above.*

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Nope, no error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because you're closing the database connection after the `csv()` finishes reading. But, as `collection.insert` is asynchronous, there's no guarantee each call has finished before the `csv` is done and `db.close()` is called.

One option is to collect the `csv` `data` into an `Array`, then `insert` all of them at once:

```
var docs = [];

csv()
  // ...
  .on('data', function (data, index) {
    docs.push(data); // or possibly: docs[index] = data;
  })
  // ...
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log("Finished reading CSV.");    

    collection.insert(docs, { safe: true }, function (error, inserted) {
      console.log("Finished all writing.");
      db.close();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I thought safe:true forces statement to wait for db's confirmation on insert?

Comment: @RishabhSagar The `safe` option doesn't force the connection to stay open, though. It only affects the callback function passed to `insert`, by ensuring that it's called "[*after the record is saved to the database*](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#insert)."

Comment: Yes, Looks like the problem was with early execution of db.close(),  guess I still haven't wrapped my head around asynch programming yet.  Thanks for your help.