# mongodb doesn't save all data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to insert some matrix in mongodb,so I wrote simple following code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;    
var matrisMaker = function(d1,d2){
    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0;i < d1;i++){
        result.push(new Array());
        for (var k = 0;k < d2;k++){
            result[i].push(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000000));
        }
    }
    return result;
};

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('matris');

    for (var counter = 0;counter < 10000000;counter++){
        var insertObject = {
                'matrisA':matrisMaker(20,20),
                'matrisB':matrisMaker(20,20),
                'resultA':new Object(),
                'resultB':new Object()
        };
        collection.insert(insertObject, function(err, docs) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });
        delete insertObject;
        if ((counter % 1000) == 0)
            console.log(counter);
    }
    db.close();
  })
```

when I see log it printed that too many records inserted,like 50,000,but when I use mongodb to count amount of records,it display less,something near 1,000 records.

```
>use test;
>db.matris.count();
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asynchronous code is flawed and your `db.close()` line executes before your asynchronous `insert` commands have all completed. You need to control the flow of your program to A) not have a million concurrent database inserts happening/queued and B) wait until they have all been processed by mongo before closing the connection. Consider a helper library such as `async.forEach` to help with this if you don't want to code it yourself.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that the connection has to be closed after each operation rather than at the end of the program before I could post my answer. This might be relevant: [Node.js code loading inconsistently to mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569830/node-js-code-loading-inconsistently-to-mongodb?rq=1)

Comment: @havarc -- that's not what Peter was suggesting. Your code incorrectly closes the connection before the work has completed (as the calls to insert are asynchronous.