# My mongodb code does not insert all data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I receive a stream of /r/n terminated data which I want to get inserted into a mongodb database.

```
tag~4~keyword~sim
tag~5~keyword~mib
tag~4~keyword~gom
tag~3~keyword~qbo
tag~6~keyword~qqq
tag~3~keyword~k94
tag~4~keyword~g93
```

I've separated them using arr.split(~) so I'll get the array representation where the first line would be represented as follows:

```
arr[0] refers to tag
arr[1] refers to 4 
arr[2] refers to keyword
arr[3] refers to sim
```

I would like to insert them into mongodb with this representation:

```
{ 
  tag: 4,
  keywords: [{ keyword: "sim" }, { keyword: "gom" }, { keyword: "g93"} ]
}
```

The gist of my nodejs/mongo client (native) code using async is as follows:

i. check collection('dat') for presence of a tag.
ii. if tag does not exist, create a document and insert the tag number
iii. next insert the keywordObj.

```
var newTagNumber = parseInt(arr[1])
var keywordObj = { keyword: arr[3] }    
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    db.collection('dat')
            .find({ tag: newTagNumber },
             { forceServerObjectId: true}).toArray((err, result) => {
               db.collection('dat').createIndex({ tag: 1 }, { unique: true })
      if (err) return callback(err)
      if (!result.length) return callback(null, false)
    })
 },
 function(arg1, callback) {
   if (!arg1) {
     db.collection('dat')
             .insertOne({ tag: newTagNumber },
              { forceServerObjectId: true }, (err, result2) => {
       if (err) return callback(err)
     })  
   } // end if

   // insert keyword object into the correct tag
   db.collection('dat')
           .updateOne({ tag: newTagNumber },
           { $push : { keywords: keywordObj }},
           { forceServerObjectId: true }, (err, result3) => {
             if (err) return callback(err)
           })
   }],
 function(err) {
   if (err) {
     if (err.message) {
       return console.log(err.message)
     }
     return console.log(err)
   }
 })
```

Using tag 4 as an example, I am supposed to have 3 keywordObj insertions into the keywords array. However, I am only getting two.

I'm not sure where have i gone wrong. Could it be due to the callbacks?

Comment: i think this is the problem i have - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637274/mongodb-doesnt-save-all-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out!

replaced all the async.waterfall code with

```
db.collection('dat')
  .updateOne({ tag: newTagNumber },
             { $push : { keywords: keywordObj }},
             { upsert: true })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('result is ' + result)
  }
```